# Should i put unit tests in a separate library? Separate subdirectory?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-organization, boost-test

I have a large library of code which has a few (much too few) unit tests; i am adding code to the library, trying to make unit tests for the new code (i also want to add unit tests for old code in future, when i get more experienced).

We currently use a custom (not very elaborate) unit-testing framework; i would like to switch to `boost.test`.

My library layout is:

- mylib1 (300 files, 70000 lines of code)

  - src

    - foo

      - foo.cpp
      - foo_part.cpp
      - foo_part.h
      - UnitTests - **should i move it outside `mylib`?**

        - foo_test1.cpp
        - foo_test2.cpp
        - foo_test3.cpp
    - bar

      - bar.cpp
      - bar_part.cpp
      - bar_part.h
      - UnitTests - **does it belong here?**

        - bar_test1.cpp
        - bar_test2.cpp
        - bar_test3.cpp
  - include

    - foo.h
    - bar.h
- mylib2 (70 files, 7000 lines of code)

  - Looks like the mylib1 above
- UnitTestFramework

  - src

    - MockObject1.cpp - **does it belong here?**
    - Asserter.cpp - *`boost.test` will replace it*
    - TestFixture.cpp - *`boost.test` will replace it*
  - include

    - MockObject1.h
    - Asserter.h - *`boost.test` will replace it*
    - TestFixture.h - *`boost.test` will replace it*

I am asking the following questions here:

- Should unit tests be part of `mylib` DLL? (I link `mylib1` and `mylib2` into one DLL)
- Should source code for unit tests be located under the `mylib1` directory?
- Since i have `mylib1` and `mylib2`, how should the corresponding unit-tests be located - in sibling directories, together, etc?
- Where should i put source code for mock objects? (they serve both `mylib1` and `mylib2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. unit tests are kind of documentation, therefore I would leave the directory structure as it is
2. mocks/fakes are helpers in unit tests, therefore I wouldn't leave them in the source directory. Create a new directory in the source, and move them there.

Actually, I would simplify it even further :

```
 + mylib1 (300 files, 70000 lines of code)
    + unit_tests
      + test_foo.cpp
      + test_bar.cpp
    + mocks
      + mock_foo.hpp
      + mock_bar.hpp
    + foo.cpp
    + foo.hpp
    + bar.cpp
    + bar.hpp
 + mylib2
similar as for mylib1
```

Comment: There is no chance i am going to "simplify" the tree structure by stuffing all 300 files into one directory. So i guess this answer mostly says "don't change the location of unit-tests, they are in the correct place".